# Can not find the specified module. Tess4j using maven

Tags: java, image, maven, tess4j

Hi I have a problem using tess4j library with java. I´m using maven.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can not find the specified module.

I´m sure that the file  setted in the path exist because the method exist returns true. The debuger show the problem in this instruction :

```
String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
```

This is the error:

```
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:45)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:283)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:219)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:168)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:152)
at Index.main(Index.java:17)
```

My dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

My code

```
import java.io.*;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;



public class Index {

public static void main(String[] args) {

File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Juan\\workspace\\TESSERACT\\src\\main\\java\\img.png");
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance(); //

try {
System.out.println( imageFile.exists());

String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
System.out.println(result);

} catch (TesseractException e) {
System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you didn't add **libtesseract302.dll** and **liblept168.dll** to the classpath.
Using Maven only enables you to download the tess4j jar, you still need to add libtesseract302.dll and liblept168.dll to your classpath.

To get Tess4J to run in Eclipse: See [**Here**](http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202294/thread/cd54d983) 
Maven does step 1 and 2 for you, you still need to do step 3.

and also [**Here**](http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202294/thread/dafb1728/), it might help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I already have those dll in the proyect, but in the next tip i tried to do the 3 step but the project doesn´t contains the file tessdll.dll

Comment: It depends if you are using 64bits or 32bits.

tessdll.dll should be found at C:\Windows\SysWOW64 or C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score 2):

For the last version of tess4j - 3.0 - it is enough to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

instead **all** previously maven dependencies which have been needed for tess4j.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing native libraries used by tess4j. Download the dlls and run your program by setting the java.library.path appropriately